# Register multiple TwigExtensions in one plugin in Craft 3

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, twigextension

In my plugins init() function I have this:

```
Craft::$app->view->registerTwigExtension(new TestTwigExtension());
```

If I duplicate that and change the Twig Extension class name, I just get an error:

> Class 'marknotton\test\Test2TwigExtension' not found

In Craft 2.x, this worked:

```
  public function addTwigExtension() {
    Craft::import('plugins.test.twigextensions.test');
    Craft::import('plugins.test.twigextensions.test2');
    return array(
      new test(),
      new test2()
    );
  }
```

It seems that approach has completely changed. I can't rename any file names, Craft::import doesn't exist anymore, and I can't pass an array into the `registerTwigExtension()` function. (*Craft 3 is scary*).

What I'm trying to achieve is a way of organising my Twig Extension files, rather than having everything in one file.

Comment: To be honest I'm a little bit confused what the problem is (I noticed our way of doing this is totally different) But does your `Test2TwigExtension` class exists and did you include it properly? Not sure what you mean with "I can't rename my filenames". When I create 2 separate twig extensions in two different files I can include them both with `Craft::$app->view->registerTwigExtension(new ClassName());`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several things going on here. This will be a general answer that can hopefully help you move forward. This example will use [Sprout Active](https://github.com/barrelstrength/sprout-active) as a reference and you can see the code here for an example of a plugin that implements multiple, simple Twig Extensions.

### Define your Twig Extension class and Namespace

In Craft 3, you can register a Twig Extension (or multiple Twig Extensions) in your Plugins `init`. While the line to register the Twig Extension is straightforward, there are a lot of other details that matter in your file and I'll comment the code below to highlight why:

```
<?php

// In Craft 3, each class you create has a namespace. You need to 
// make sure that this is referenced in any other classes that use this class
namespace barrelstrength\sproutactive;

// We're referencing the namespaces of other classes in this class too.
// We use the Craft Plugin class, to create our plugin
use craft\base\Plugin;

// You'll create this file next. We need to identify the namespace
// of the Twig Extension we'll be importing so Craft knows where it is
// when we reference `new TwigExtensions()` below
use barrelstrength\sproutactive\twig\TwigExtensions;

class SproutActive extends Plugin
{
    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        // Register the Twig Extensions file. We could name this anything
        // and put this anywhere in our folder structure now. As long as 
        // we reference the namespace properly above, Craft will be able to 
        // find it. We can create multiple Twig Extensions within this
        // TwigExtensions Class or create multiple files to manage our
        // Twig Extensions and import those classes too.
        Craft::$app->view->twig->addExtension(new TwigExtensions());
    }
}
```

---

### Twig 2 updated several things too

Once we get the extensions loaded, you can create extensions similar to before, however, Craft 3 uses Twig 2 which introduces several breaking changes on it's own. You can see some discussion of the [Twig 2 front-end changes](https://github.com/craftcms/docs/blob/master/en/changes-in-craft-3.md#twig-2) in the Craft docs but the docs don't discuss the API changes.

In Twig 2, `Twig_SimpleFunction` replaces `Twig_Function_Method` and `Twig_Filter_Method` so you'll need to update any Craft 2 Twig Extensions code to use `Twig_SimpleFunction`

In the Sprout Active `TwigExtensions` Class you can see how the class creates multiple Twig functions within the `getFunctions` method.

```
public function getFunctions()
{
    return [
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('active', [$this, 'getActive']),
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('activeClass', [$this, 'getActiveClass'], ['is_safe' => ['html']]),
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('segment', [$this, 'getSegment']),
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('segmentClass', [$this, 'getSegmentClass'], ['is_safe' => ['html']])
    ];
}
```

Comment: So sorry it's taken 11 months to show my appreciation for the Ben! I'm not sure what happened, I'm alway quick to give thanks normally. This is a great and very detailed answer. Thank you very much! :)